# Kohana 3.2 ORM define foreign keys consisting of two columns

Tags: php, orm, joomla, kohana

I am building an application on the Kohana framework. For content management, I will be using the Joomla framework, so our copywriters can easily add and edit content in a to them familiar UI.

I have defined several categories to which an article can belong to. E.g. blog (`catid = 1`) and product (`catid = 2`). With the `xreference` column in the joomla content table, the user must assign the article to a specific id in the category selected (because `Model_Blog` can contain `id = 1`, as well as `Model_Product` can).

So every article in Joomla consists of a unique combination of `catid` and `xreference`. Now I want to bind this one-to-one relation to my Kohana ORM models (e.g. `Model_Blog`), but the standard Kohana ORM `$_has_one` property only supports foreign keys consisting of one column instead of multiple AFAIK.

I tried the following, which, of course, doesn't work:

```
protected $_has_one = array(
  'content' => array('model' => 'cms_content', 'foreign_key' => 'xreference', 'catid' => '1')
);
```

Can anyone advise me on how to bind this relationship correctly?

Comment: http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/orm/relationships

Comment: Thank you for your comment, hakre. Unfortunately the Kohana documentation is not sufficient, because it doesn't provide an explanation on how to define a relationship based on **multiple** columns.

Comment: Create a view in MySQL that contains the relationship already. Then create a model for that view - in case Kohana does not support that.

Comment: Horrible discovering !!!!

Answer (score 3):

After a lookup in the source code, I found out that Kohana ORM doesn't support the feature I described and I had to extend the ORM module (which is because of Kohana's nature, a piece of cake :)), to implement multi-column FK's.

```
class ORM_Modified extends ORM {
    public function __get($column) {
        if (isset($this->_has_one[$column])) {
            $model = $this->_related($column);
            $pk = $this->pk();

            // Use this model's primary key value (if no value set) and foreign model's column(s)
            if(!is_array($this->_has_one[$column]['foreign_key'])) {
                $col = ;
                $model->where($model->_object_name.'.'.$this->_has_one[$column]['foreign_key'], '=', $pk);
            } else {
                foreach($this->_has_one[$column]['foreign_key'] as $col => $value) {
                    $model->where($model->_object_name.'.'.$col, '=', $value == null ? $pk : $value);
                }
            }
            $model->find();

            return $this->_related[$column] = $model;
        } else {
            return parent::__get($column); 
        }
    }
}
```

Now I can define an array of columns which form the foreign key in the relationship with the following syntax:

```
protected $_has_one = array(
    'content' => array('model' => 'cms_content', 'foreign_key' => array('xreference' => null, 'catid' => '1'))
);
```

Please note that my solution only applies to a 1-to-1 relationship, because in my case there's no need to implement it for 1-to-many, although I suspect this would require a similar modification

Comment: Just used this to solve a problem. Thanks!  My version of Kohana needed some changes ($model->_object_name became $model->table_name()) but for the most part, it worked perfectly.